# Django - submitting any form field dependant on permission

Tags: python, django, django-permissions

I'm looking for a way to control the users ability to submit a form field using permissions. We have 3 fields and the condition is that of any of the fields submitted the user does not have the permission for that field, we must return Permission denied.

**Note: User_1 has the permission to edit field_1 and field_2 only, via a group.**

My question is should I be using `PERMISSION_KEY_MAP` to control the mapping of a field and permission or is there a better method? I have attempted below and it works as expected.

**Fields**

```
field_1 [Pass]
field_2 [Pass]
field_3 [Fail]
```

**Views.py**

```
class SampleView(
    ObjectPermissionRequiredMixin,
    BreadCrumbsMixin,
    NestedLookupMixin,
    UpdateView,
):
    def _get_permission_to_submit_field(self, field_keys):
        for field in field_keys:
            if not self.request.user.has_perm(
                PERMISSION_KEY_MAP[field],
            ):
                return False
        return True

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        field_keys = list(self.request.POST.keys())

        if not self._get_permission_to_submit_field(field_keys):
            raise PermissionDenied

        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**PERMISSION_KEY_MAP**

```
PERMISSION_KEY_MAP = {
    'field_1': 'app.edit_field_1',
    'field_2': 'app.edit_field_2',
}
```